# How to optimize ServiceStack.Text performance when deserializing to enums with DataContract

Tags: .net, servicestack, datacontract, servicestack-text

Is there a way to optimize ServiceStack.Text (version 5.4.0) performance when deserializing enumerated values to .Net enums that have [DataContract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts) and [EnumMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/enumeration-types-in-data-contracts) attributes set? I would like to use EnumMember attributes to defined the serialized names, but unfortunately ServiceStack.Text seems to need about three time more time to deserialize using this method, as opposed to deserializing based on plain enum member names.

For example, consider this simple C# test program:

```
using ServiceStack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;

namespace ServiceStackPerformance
{
    public class Program
    {
        [DataContract]
        enum DataContractEnum
        {
            [EnumMember(Value = "first")]
            First = 0,
            [EnumMember(Value = "second")]
            Second = 1,
        }

        enum PlainEnum
        {
            first = 0,
            second = 1,
        }

        [DataContract]
        class DataContractEnumList
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "values")]
            public List<DataContractEnum> Values { get; set; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        class PlainEnumList
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "values")]
            public List<PlainEnum> Values { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size = 100000;
            string test = GenerateTestString(size);
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopwatch.Start();
            var dataContractEnumList = test.FromJson<DataContractEnumList>();
            var dataContractMs = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            stopwatch.Restart();
            var plainType = test.FromJson<PlainEnumList>();
            var plainMs = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            Console.WriteLine($"Deserializing input of size {2*size+1} to data contract enum took {dataContractMs} ms.");
            Console.WriteLine($"Deserializing input of size {2*size+1} to simple enum took {plainMs} ms.");
        }

        private static string GenerateTestString(int size)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder(10*size);
            builder.Append("{\"values\":[");
            for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                builder.Append("\"first\",\"second\",");
            }
            builder.Append("\"first\"]}");

            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

output is as follows:

```
Deserializing input of size 200001 to data contract enum took 3520 ms.
Deserializing input of size 200001 to simple enum took 1131 ms.
```

Are there any caching or other performance optimizations that I could enable to avoid the slowdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance of Enums with `[EnumMember]` should be improved with [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/ee8c70d871f5d613e8ffb5316d4c3e7f8401ecf0) and deserialization of Enums in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/554402c72d802379136dd0621bc15017ce38a0d4) which utilizes cached enum info.

This change is available from v5.4.1 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thank you for quick response! I can confirm that the new version cuts the *serialization* time for DataContract enums to about 1/10 of 5.4.0 benchmark. However deserialization time, which was actually the content of my question, does not seem to be affected in any way. From reviewing the code in the commit you link, plus running the code through debugger, it seems that the new _CachedTypeInfo_ is not used during deserialization. Could you still check that?

Comment: @OttoUrpelainen I've updated it to use Cached EnumInfo which is now available from v4.5.1 on MyGet. You'll need to clear your NuGet cache to download the latest version.

Comment: Hi! I can confirm that the new version also speeds up deserialization of data contract enums so that their processing speed is comparable to plain enums. However, you may be interested in result of a benchmark with actual payload, not the simple one from the question that is suitable to be published in Stack Overflow: For a large json file in format that we actually use, containing mainly Strings, Decimals and DateTimes, the performance has degraded so that previously 500 ms deserialization is now around 1000 ms, and serialization has a similar impact.

Comment: Marking this answer correct, since the DataContract issue is now solved with 5.4.1 version of ServiceStack.Text, though I am not quite sure if we want to update ourselves, due to problem I describe in the preceding comment.

Comment: @OttoUrpelainen if you can upload a project on GitHub with a benchmark of what’s degraded I can investigate

Comment: Never mind, I cannot replicate my own results. After cleaning up the test code, the results now show that enum handling is faster and the other load I have has not seen change.